# Which of the following functions are linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: This is the problem]

I think that B, C, and E are linear, but I'm not sure. I know for sure C is linear, because it is just a scalar, and B looks linear since it would just product the identity matrix. Other than that I'm not so sure and I'm on my last try.

Comment: B, C, and D can't be linear, because they don't satisfy $F(\lambda x) = \lambda F(x)$.

Comment: The answer will be that A and E will be linear, but the rest will not be.  Note what happens to each function when, for example, you multiply $x$ by $2$.